# Proftpd user migration login denied

Tags: migration, password, proftpd

I migrated ProFTPd on a bigger server including ftpd.passwd and proftpd.conf.
The service is running. Unfortunately none of the old passes would work.
To analyze the situation I have re-generated one of the old passes with ftpasswd and it will generate a different string in ftpd.passwd. I would assume it should be the same as on the old server?

Has anybody an idea how it I could migrate while keeping the user passwords valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question.
1st - I solved this:
"ftpasswd: /bin/false is not among the valid system shells.  Use of.." 
2nd - I had to adjust some iptables rule, cause of my hoster.

So, if you get "login incorrect" it is not necessarily the password. Check the log.